# Best way to approach this PDE question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am okay with the first question, but stuck on 2 (solving the given PDE)
[Given PDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tpb2.png)

I have found the characteristics to be:
$\frac{dx}{d\tau}=x-2u$, $\frac{dt}{d\tau}=1$, $\frac{du}{d\tau}=-u$ and got $t(\tau)=\tau+c_t$, $x(\tau)=(x-2u)\tau+c_x$ and $u(\tau)=c_ue^{-\tau}$ where $c_x, c_t, c_u$ are constants. I am unsure if I have computed my characteristics correctly and where to progress from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dx}{dt}=x-2u, \frac{dy}{dt}=1,\frac{du}{dt}=-u$. This gives

$y(t)=t+c_2, u(t)=c_3e^{-t}$ and $\dfrac{dx}{dt}-x=-c_3e^{-t}\implies x(t)=c_1e^t+\frac{c_3}{2}e^{-t}$. Now substitute the initial condition and get the answer.